# Kafka Cluster : Use of 9091 port

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform

Confluent Kafka (Community) mentions port 9091 is required for inter broker communication.
What should be the firewall rules for this port on AWS .
Setup: 3 node broker , 3 node zookeeper

Refer
https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/system-requirements.html

Answer (score 0):

As it says, it's internal topic replication only, so you should only allow traffic within the VPC, preferably only from the brokers (whitelist the broker ips, exclude everything else)